# Excel 2010 INDEX MATCH formula failure--need help to resolve

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I am working with 4 columns across two sheets.

Sheet_1 contains a column of text and a corresponding column of values.

Sheet_2 contains a column of text, some of which can be matched to the text column in sheet_1 and some cannot; all rows of cells in sheet_1 text column should match a cell row of text in the sheet_2 text column, but not vice versa because sheet_2 text column contains additional text rows.

The fourth column is a blank column in sheet_2 where I want to return the value of the second column in sheet_1.

The text column in sheet_1 is not in the same order as the text column in sheet_2.  All columns contain thousands of rows.

[image]

In the past, just a couple of days ago on the same computer and in the same Excel program, I successfully used this formula:

> =IFERROR(INDEX('Sheet_1'!B:B,MATCH('Sheet_2'!A1,'Sheet_1'!A:A,0)),"Not Found")

In the past use of this formula, it would successfully match the text of number in sheet_2, cell A1 to the text or number in sheet_1, column A, return the corresponding value or number in the cell from the indexed column B in sheet_2 to the cell I placed the formula.  If there was not a match found, then the formula would return the text "Not Found."

Even if I go back to where I have used the formula successfully and retype the exact same formula OR cut and paste it, sometimes it will work and sometimes it will not.

I have tried reformatting all the columns to text using the text to columns function.  I have tried copying into Notepad and then pasting back into the worksheet.  I have tried different variations of formulas I have found online and cannot get anything to work.

At this point if I get a "N/A" instead of "Not Found," I would be happy.

Please help.

Thank you, Cooper

Answer (score 1):

Without access to the original spreadsheet, I'm not sure how much we can help with an intermittent issue.  I would advise that you break the formula into its components (you can hide the columns if required) so you can see where the error is being introduced.

So for example on Sheet2 in column C put `=MATCH(...)`, then in column D put `=INDEX(...)` and so on:
[image]

Comment: Okay, I am trying what you suggested, very good suggestion might I add, I did not think about breaking the pieced apart into separate formulas.

Comment: Anyway, it looks like my worksheet is not recognizing the "=" as a signal to start a formula.  Up in the fx line, the formulas still highlights, etc., however, when I leave the cell I write the formula in, I only see the text of the formula like it is just text and not a hidden formula.  I do not get any kind of any error message or other response to my formula.

Comment: Ensure your cell format is `General` and not `Text`.  After changing to `General`, edit the cell and accept, it should re-evaluate the formula.

Comment: This is happening with even the simplest formula of =A1+A2 where A1 has the number 2 in it and A2 has the number 2 in it.  I do not get 4.  What I see when I leave the cell where I wrote the formula is =A1+A2.

Comment: If I create a fresh new sheet in this same workbook, I do not have the same issue.  I am working with so much data that it is not very easy to move.  Plus, I have already pasted into notebook and back again.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you check the cell formatting?  Sounds like the cell is formatted as `Text`.

Comment: The cell I want to lookup is text and the column I want to look it up in is text and the value I want to return ideally should be formatted as a number, but I have tried formatting it as both a number and text.  It seems like I can't even get my formula to run because I don't even get an error message.  I only see my formula in my cell after I press enter.

Comment: If you format as `Text`, it won't evaluate the formula.  Format as `General`, edit the cell and accept, it should re-evaluate the formula.

Comment: Clarification question:  format all the columns as general or only the column where my formulas will be?

Comment: Just the cells with formulas.  Also check you haven't changed the setting for [automatic recalculation](https://www.pryor.com/blog/why-is-your-excel-formula-not-calculating/)

Comment: [This page](https://ion.icaew.com/itcounts/b/weblog/posts/exceltipoftheweek53causesofformulasnotcalculating) shows a quick way to make all the formulas recalculate: find `=` and replace with `=`

Comment: Okay, I fixed it.  Thanks for your help.  I just ended up recreating my data from the source into a fresh workbook and my formula worked again.  Do not know what it was.  Thanks again..